# How to set source repository in Jenkins?

Tags: git, docker, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and think I missed a step when setting up Jenkins.
I have Jenkins 2.401.3 running in a local docker container. I have a git repo on my local linux machine.

Basic hello world examples, such as "Through the classic UI" from here work as expected: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/

I start having trouble when I try to pull in my source code. I want my Jenkins pipeline to use the Dockerfile in the git repo to build the rest of my code.

I would like to do something similar to the example from https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#dockerfile

```
pipeline {
    agent { dockerfile true }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
                sh 'svn --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the example code, Jenkins does not find my dockerfile. When I add a new stage to checkout my code, it does seem to find my code, but won't use the dockerfile in the next stage.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    //agent { dockerfile true } //this line doesn't work

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout scmGit(branches: [[name: '*/master']], extensions: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: '/myPath/myRepo/']])
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            agent { dockerfile true }
            
            steps {
                sh 'python3 --version' //this should output the version installed by my Dockerfile
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I never set a "source repository" and can't find an option to do so.
What do I need to do for Pipeline to recognize my Dockerfile?

Comment: #1 To host a git repository in the same host of your continuous integration is extremely rare. Could you use a private github repository?  #2 What do you mean by "source repository"? Are you talking about the git url which is used for git clone command?

Comment: #1 Right now I'm trying to play with tools to see what we want to use, so everything is on my local machine. For production use, we will move to servers. #2 "Source repository" is a term used in the Jenkins documentation for where it gets the dockerfile for `agent { dockerfile true }` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workable solution. If you use Pipeline script from SCM, the `agent {dockerfile true}` command can find the dockerfile.

Instructions to change:

1. In the Jenkins web GUI, select the Pipeline
2. Click Configure
3. Copy text of Pipeline script from the form window into a new file called Jenkinsfile in your repo
4. Change the Pipeline Definition from 'Pipeline script' to 'Pipeline script from SCM'
5. Click Save
6. Click Build Now

The 'Checkout' stage in my original post is now redundant. I don't understand why my original method didn't work, but using a Jenkinsfile is a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dir() to specific workdir on jenkins machine, for example

```
stage ("Checkout") {
    steps {
        dir('source'){
           checkout scmGit(branches: [[name: '*/master']], 
                    extensions: [], 
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[url: '/myPath/myRepo/']])
        }
    }
}
```

make it easy to handle task and less of confuse for Jenkins machine.

Comment: The `dir('source')` function does download a copy of my source code to a new folder called 'source' in my workspace, but the `agent { dockerfile true }` command looks in a different location, so it still does not work. I think your method would work to build a dockerfile in a step using `sh 'docker compose up --build'`.